# Header files in Anjuta

Tags: c

What is used instead of  header in anjuta for a simple C program to give an output? I am new to programming and only used turbo c previously. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use stdio.h, not conio.h. conio.h is specific to consoles, while stdio is standard input/ouput. If all you are doing is character fetching, you will find getc() etc in stdio.h.

Answer (score 2):

Anjuta is just an IDE. I assume you are looking for something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Save this into a file called helloworld.c and compile it. It should run.

Comment: Im sorry to ask again but in turbo C the header file used is <conio.h>... and getch() is used. is there anything similar?

Comment: Anjuta is just an IDE for e.g. plain C and therefor kind of a frontend for a compiler like gcc. Turbo C might differ from it, as having Turbo PASCAL in mind, it's combining IDE and compiler. So according to conio.h a clear ... I have no clue.